# Error while iterating Integer keys in dictionary "int object is not subscriptable " Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary data = {21: False, 22: False, 23: False, 31: False}

If i check this type it is coming as <class 'dict'> thats fine,

I am trying to iterate over it and assign values to protobuff variable, the below is my sample code looks like

```
 def get_encoded_payload(self, payload):
        self.logger.debug("started")
        
         // my payload data looks like this 
        // payload= {21: False, 22: False, 23: False, 31: False}


        #set proto attributes of device status using json data
        device_status = DeviceStatusMsg()
        device = Device()

        #loop over current device status and set the each device state inot device proto
        for each_device in payload:

            device.type = each_device["device_type"] // Getting error here [ 'int' object is not subscriptable ]
            device.state = each_device["device_status"]
```

I am trying to assign  `key, value` to `device.type and device.state`

Comment: `each_device` contains the key of the dictionary, not the dictionary itself. either use `.items()` to iterate or access using `payload[each_device]`.

Comment: @Vishal, i tried using .items() , please check this code `for each_device in payload.items():

            device.type = each_device["device_type"]
            device.state = each_device["device_status"]` it is giving me this error `**tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str**`

Comment: try with `for key, value in payload.items():`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_encoded_payload(payload):

    for key,value in payload.items(): 
    # dictonery cannot be iterated the way you are iterating hence you are getting 
    # Getting error here [ 'int' object is not subscriptable ]
        b = key
        a = value
        print("a",a)
        print("b",b)
payload= {21: False, 22: False, 23: False, 31:False}

print(type(payload))
get_encoded_payload(payload)
```

You are incrementing the python dictionary the wrong way. I suggest you read https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/. Please take a look at the above code snippet for your reference too.

Comment: thank you for quick reply, i tried the sample you have share but i am getting this error `'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: Please check your "payload" variable data type, it should be of type dictionary. i.e, payload= {21: False, 22: False, 23: False, 31: False}. List donot support items().